# WordPress installation on valet php 8 (PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception Table 'wp_options' doesn't exist in wp-includes/wp-db.php:2056)

Tags: mysql, installation

When I was installing WordPress using my Laravel valet, this is showing, and it stopped installing by the following message:

```
[15-Dec-2021 18:09:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'tutor.wp_options' doesn't exist in /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2056
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/wp-db.php(2056): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT option_n...')
#1 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/wp-db.php(1945): wpdb->_do_query('SELECT option_n...')
#2 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/wp-db.php(2695): wpdb->query('SELECT option_n...')
#3 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/option.php(284): wpdb->get_results('SELECT option_n...')
#4 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/functions.php(1730): wp_load_alloptions()
#5 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/load.php(752): is_blog_installed()
#6 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed()
#7 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-config.php(107): require_once('/Users/hasan/Si...')
#8 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/Users/hasan/Si...')
#9 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/Users/hasan/Si...')
#10 /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/Users/hasan/Si...')
#11 /Users/hasan/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(234): require('/Users/hasan/Si...')
#12 {main}
  thrown in /Users/hasan/Sites/tutor/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2056
```

Comment: Welcome to wpse! installing on php version 7.4 outputs the same fatal error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use php 7.4. So verify first it is installed :

```
brew install php@7.4
```

Then with valet :

```
valet use php@7.4
```

then

```
valet restart
```

Comment: Thanks, @CRavon. It works...

Comment: You're welcome @Hasan Tareq, I happen to have the exact same problem two days ago.